# Скачать большой файл из ФТП через PHP с подгрузкой

Tags: php, ftp, header

На FTP сервере хранятся файлы от 0,1 до 300 мб.

Нужно, чтоб пользователи могли скачивать эти файлы с сайта из браузера.

Сейчас функция, отвечающая за выдачу файлов  выглядит так:

```
public function save($path, $filename = null) {

    if(empty($filename)) {
        $filename = basename ( $path );
        $file = $path;
    } else {
        $file = $path . '/' . $filename;  
    }


    ob_start();
    $result = @ftp_get($this->_conn_id, "php://output", $file, FTP_BINARY);
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    $datasize = ob_get_length();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    if ($result) {
        $f = ['data' => $data, 'size' => $datasize];

        ftp_close($this->_conn_id);
        if (!$f) {
            error("Error. File ".$file." not found.", true);
        }

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $f['size']);

        echo $f['data'];
        exit();
    } else {
        error("Error!!!! File ".$file." not found.", true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Но у нее проблема: файл сначала скачивается полностью с FTP на сервер с PHP, а потом отдается на вывод пользователю. Для небольших файлов это не смертельно, а для больших - приходится ждать минутами, пока в браузере вылезет окно "Сохранить файл как...".

Что тут можно сделать, чтоб ускорить или оптимизировать этот процесс? Как-нибудь файл на части разбивать или еще что...? Потому что скачивать файлы по 300 мб каждый раз на php серв - жирно как-то.

Comment: А отдать готовый для скачивания файла, по ссылке, никак что-ли?

Comment: ftp серв удаленный. В нем на каждый месяц собирается по 8-10 гигов файлов, - хранить всё это на серве с приложением - нет уж. Приложение как раз читает директории ftp, создает ссылки для скачивания файлов и отдает их пользователю

Comment: Какая-то сомнительная идея, отдавать через php. Уж лучше через web-сервер это делать,`nginx` желательно через `XSendfile`. Хотя у `apache`, есть тоже `mod_xsendfile`.

Comment: Не вижу, как это можно увязать с удаленным ftp-сервером. К тому же доступ к нему по IP - всего лишь с двух машин. На одной - только фтп серв, на второй - только наше приложение. Т.е. не получится просто так вбить "ftp://логин:пароль@хост/файл".

Я понимаю, что решений "как скачать файл с фтп" - хоть 100500. Но тут лишь проблема одного модуля, перелопачивать всё приложение никто не будет. Нужно скачивание через PHP